# Number of terms when counting from the ceiling of (n+1)/2 to n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
$$

What is the justification for concluding that counting to $n$ from $\ceil{ \frac{n+1}{2}}$ counts $\ceil{\frac{n}{2}}$ terms?

The context for this question is my textbook (*Discrete Mathematics* by Johnsonbaugh). The author gives a lowerbound of $\frac{n^2}{4}$ for the sum $ 1+2+ \dots + n$. He writes:

> $\dots$ first throw away approximately the first half of the terms, to obtain
>
> $$  1 + 2 + \dots + n \ge \ceil{\frac{n+1}{2}} + \dots + (n-1) + n \\ 
> > \\ \ge \ceil{\frac{n+1}{2}} + \dots + \ceil{\frac{n+1}{2}} +\ceil{\frac{n+1}{2}} \\  
> \ge \ceil{\frac{n}{2}}\ceil{\frac{n+1}{2}} \ge \frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{n}{2} = \frac{n^2}{4} $$
> *for $ x \ge 1$.*

Johnsonbaugh, R. (2018). Discrete Mathematics,eBook, Global Edition (8th Edition). Pearson International Content. https://bookshelf.vitalsource.com/books/9781292233727

Comment: What is the definition of $x $?

Comment: Have you considered even and odd values of $n$ separately? That is, try assuming $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$ first, then $n = 2k + 1$ next. For each of these cases, you can write $\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil$ and $\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil$ in terms of $k$, which are (hopefully) simpler for you to analyse.

Comment: @WarrenTheRabbit Adjusting my previous (now removed) comment after the edit: [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients) $\,n = \lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil+\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil\,$, if you "*throw away approximately the first half of the terms*" meaning the first $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil$ terms, then you are left with $\,\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil\,$ terms, each one $\,\ge \lceil \frac{n+1}{2}\rceil \ge \frac{n}{2}\,$, and the statement follows.